# Файлы .uuid в директории .fonts и поддиректориях

Tags: linux, файлы, fedora, hidden

Заметил, что в директории .fonts и поддиректориях создается файлы **.uuid**
gримерно такого содержания

> bd57928b-9c18-4b71-80c7-6c3f186c2b1d

Причем во всех директориях содержимое разное, но размер один — 36 байтов.

При удалении они создаются заново.
В других скрытых директориях (начинающихся с точки) таких файлов нет.
Мне места не жалко, но очень интересно, что это за файл и зачем он нужен.

Сейчас установлена **RFRemix 28, 64bit.**

В более ранних версиях такого не замечал, поэтому и заинтересовался.

Comment: *UUID — Universally Unique ID* https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID

Comment: @0andriy, я знаю что это за файлы. Не могу понять, зачем они в директории со шрифтами. Раньше-то системе они не были нужны (До 28 Федоры).

Comment: Так вы определитесь, знаете вы «что это за файлы» или нет? Впрочем, по аббревиатуре должно быть понятно «зачем».

Comment: @0andriy аббревиатура понятна, а всё-таки зачем — непонятно